# SELECT SUM() always returns 0 when it should be xxx amount

Tags: php, mysql

Needing help with SELECT SUM()... This is all my query and whenever it runs the result is always 0 any body see my problem cant seem to figure it out...

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT SUM(credit_amount) FROM a_creditpurchase");

$creditsbought = 0;
while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $creditsbought += $row['credit_amount'];
}
echo $creditsbought;
```

Comment: Your query is not returning any column named `credit_amount` so there is nothing to add.  Also, a `while` loop seems like overkill for a query that is guaranteed to return exactly one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT SUM(credit_amount) as sum FROM a_creditpurchase");

$creditsbought = 0;
$row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$creditsbought = $row['sum'];

echo $creditsbought;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the SQL query with `GROUP(credit_amount)`?

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT SUM(credit_amount) FROM a_creditpurchase GROUP(credit_amount)");
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked great keune Thanks

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT SUM(credit_amount) as totalAmount FROM a_creditpurchase");

while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$creditsbought += $row['totalAmount'];
}
```